# Как получить несколько строк и если каких-то нет, то подставить по умолчанию?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть табличка `settings`:

```
create table settings (
  name text,
  value int
);
```

Со значениями:

```
insert into settings values ('A', 20), ('B', 30);
```

Мне нужно эти значения объединить в одну строку, и если нет значений, подставить по умолчанию. Пока я придумал следующее:

```
select a.value a_value, B.value b_value, COALESCE(C.value, 1) c_value from settings a
  left join settings B on B.name='B'
  left join settings C on B.name='C'
WHERE A.name='A';
```

Но у меня проблема в том, что если будет отсутствовать значение А, то результат будет нулевой. Как быть? Вот пример для потестить: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6651a

Comment: Какой результат должен быть для этих входных данных? Сколько строк, какие колонки и какие в них значения?

Comment: @RomanKonoval должна быть одна строка. У таблицы уникальность по всем колонкам, двух одинаковых строк не будет. По простому у меня есть параметры А, В, С, которые могут быть или не быть в таблице. И если их нет, то вместо них дефолтные значения.

Comment: Покажите примеры. Исходные данные - требуемый ответ. Как для варианта, когда "есть", так и для варианта, когда "нет".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
select 
   coalesce(A.value, 11) a_value,
   coalesce(B.value, 22) b_value,
   coalesce(C.value, 33) c_value
from (values (1)) as t (v)
 left join settings A on A.name = 'A'
 left join settings B on B.name = 'B'
 left join settings C on C.name = 'C'
```